# Clarification on tags: Android and Monodroid

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

On the "normal" stackoverflow site, is anyone aware of how "android" tag subscriber/watchers
feel toward questions being asked that contain C#/Monodroid code (versus Java code) ?

I've never had a problem before with this, but due to recent questions getting unexplained downvotes, I'm not sure ?

There is separate tags for Android (Java) and MonoDroid (C#), but I've always mixed them with no problems until now.

thanks.

Comment: I believe, that questions dedicated specifically to programming on monodroid, where you are only using c# functionality then you use MonoDroid. Otherwise if it is java-specific functionality then use android.

Comment: I can see `android monodroid` being applied to a post, but only in cases where `monodroid` is the platform. Tagging something simply `android` bust listing `monodroid` wouldn't be appropriate. (almost like `javascript` and `jquery`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work with Mono for Android, and I can see how the code samples might be confusing to Java Android developers.

The API is the same, except the code can look foreign (Properties vs getters/setters) however I think there is more that is the same than different.

I think including the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag would be appropraite, however I would make sure you also tag with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [monodroid](/questions/tagged/monodroid) so that people who want to ignore questions related to MonoDroid see upfront that the question potentially includes C# code.

If the questions is about something MonoDroid specific, i.e the Runtime enviroment I would not include the Android tag.

Comment: Ahh, good idea with the c# tag. I've always added android + monodroid together, but was never sure. Thank you.

Comment: An conversely, if a question is posted with an android tag (and no monodroid or c# tags), should it not be answered in c# code ? I just got downvoted twice in this scenario, and my answer was identical to the others (but I included a snippet, no one else did). Ive been getting 2 DV's on everything I post lately, so it just might be my script/stalker thingy.